# Deploying consul on existing kubernetes cluster in GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, consul, hashicorp

I am trying to deploy Consul service mesh to an existing kubernetes cluster running on GKE. The cluster already has workloads running in production.

For this matter i followed the following guide

https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/consul/service-mesh-deploy

This is without TLS, ACL etc, as I didn't want it to be intrusive to the cluster to start of with and I could enable it later. So after a successful deployment I wanted to enable ACL, too this end I ran the following helm command.

```
helm upgrade consul hashicorp/consul --namespace consul --set global.acls.manageSystemACLs=true
```

After this was done, most of the existing deployments / workloads seemed to be down, and the fix was to uninstall Consul again.

So now I am left wondering what went wrong, is something wrong with my method of installing Consul on the cluster or is it something else?

Help is greatly appreciated

**EDIT** Add yaml file

```
global:
  name: consul
  datacenter: dc1
  metrics:
    enabled: true
    enableAgentMetrics: true
server:
  replicas: 1
  resources:
    requests:
      memory: "200Mi"
      cpu: "100m"
    limits:
      memory: "1Gi"
      cpu: "1"
client:
  resources:
    requests:
      memory: "200Mi"
      cpu: "100m"
    limits:
      memory: "1Gi"
      cpu: "1"
ui:
  enabled: true
  service:
    type: LoadBalancer
connectInject:
  enabled: true
  default: true
controller:
  enabled: true
```

Comment: have you checked out this guide on how to deploy [Consul on GKE](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/consul/kubernetes-gke-google?utm_content=k8s&utm_source=consul.io&utm_medium=docs&utm_term=gke)?

Comment: @BryanL yes I have, it is basically what I have done. I will update the answer with the yaml i have used.

Comment: can you share what is in the failing pods logs **kubectl logs ${POD_NAME} ${CONTAINER_NAME}**

Comment: Also look why the pods are failing with kubectl describe.

Comment: I would suspect the consul deployment added pod security or network policies breaking the other services.

Comment: I would suggest trying again with `global.acls.manageSystemACLs=false`, but since you're operating on a production environment, maybe too risky